# Getting fields of a custom content type in node twig template drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I have developed a custom content type with some custom fields which works nice, I have also assigned a template to it.The Problem is I cannot access the fields against the post in my template. let me show you my code

**[module].module**

```
 <?php
    function [module]_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
    {
        return [
            'node__[module] => [
                'variables' => [],
            ]
        ];
    }
```

**templates/node--[module].html**

```
<h1>Uneeb</h1>
```

below is the yml file of field i created and want to access in twig template

**[module]/config/install/field.field.node.[module].location.yml**

```
# field.field.node.cspace.location.yml
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - field.storage.node.location
    - node.type.cspace
  module:
    - text
id: node.cspace.location
field_name: location
entity_type: node
bundle: cspace
label: 'Script Location'
description: 'More specific information about the car brand'
required: true
translatable: false
default_value: {  }
default_value_callback: ''
settings:
  display_summary: false
field_type: text_with_summary
```

the node template works perfectly fine I can the text uneeb on the page and only for this specific content type which i originally wanted now I want to access data against this content type.I have tried a bunch of solutions but none of them seems to be working and I cannot access my custom content fields inside twig template can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add `base hook` to your theme declaration:

```php
    function [module]_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
    {
        return [
            'node__[module]' => [
                'variables' => [],
            ],
            'base hook' => 'node'
        ];
    }
```

Then in your `node--[module].html.twig`, you can print content field like this:

```
{{ content.field_xyz[0] }}
```

with `field_xyz` is machine name of the field.

Comment: Kien Thanks for your comment, how can i find out the machine name of the field? i'm a newbie to drupal my apologies for any foolish questions,furthermore the i tried printing out {{ content }} it returns null

Comment: I have updated the question and added the yml file of content field in case i did something wrong over there

Comment: Your field's machine name is `location`. And you should delete the code in file `[module].module` so as not to overwrite the default template in core. Remember to flush the cache

Comment: if i comment out the code in [module].module file it ignores the template file and renders the default view,so i had to add that code back , but still {{content.location[0]}} doesnot work i have seen this solution in many places but doesnot work in my case any wild guess what might the problem?

Comment: can it be that maybe twig requries a specific pattern and i am not following that i havent used twig before

Comment: I think I got the problem. What do you want when creating template `node__[module]`? A custom page or a content detail page?

Comment: I'm not sure of the differences, what i want to do is to render some html within the content part of the page meaning the sidebar ,topbar should stay the same and the content part or you can say the body part should render the html i specify with content fields.so right now it does work like that the node__[module] template overrides the content part of the page but cant access the {{content.location[0]}}

Comment: Let's discuss in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228831/room-for-kien-nguyen-and-uneeb-meer)